# How to setup/import a multi maven module SVN-connected project in Eclipse the best way?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I use Eclipse (3.4.2*), m2eclipse (0.9.8), Subversive (0.7.9) and SVNKit (1.6.10) on a Windows 7 64-bit PC.

Can someone give some advice on how to set up (import, really) a multi module maven project in Eclipse, while still fulfilling below requirements?

1. Eclipse should maintain one project for each sub module, according to the general recommendations (if I remember correctly the subversive plugin doesn't even support nested modules in one single project anymore).
2. Eclipse should recognice all java files as proper java classes (ie they should be findable using the "Open Type" dialog, as well as all other normal java functionallity in Eclipse, like displaying type/call hierarchy).
3. All target-folders and .svn files and folders should be excluded when using the file search or "Open Resource" dialog, and all svn-folders should be excluded/hidden in the Navigator.
4. The "Open Resource" should not display any single file more then once.
5. When I open a file using the "Open Resource" or "Open Type" dialog, I should be able to see the svn-history for it.
6. I should be able to do an svn switch on the entire maven project (ie including all sub modules) in one single step.

The project structure, in simple terms:

```
<main project folder>
|
|
---- pom.xml
|
|
---- module 1
|    |
|    |
|    --- pom.xml
|    --- src/main/java
|
---- module 2
[...]
```

The main problem I have is with requirement 2. Eclipse doesn't seem to understand that the java files are proper java classes unless it finds them in the sub modules. To do that, while still fullfilling requirement 4 I must exclude a bunch of folders in main eclipse project when configuring my Working Set. But then I break requirement 5, since Eclipse will then open the java file in the sub module project, and that project is not connected to SVN. And if I try and fix that by connecting the sub module project to SVN I break requirement 6 (if I do a swich on the main project, the sub module projects still thinks they are connected to the old branch/trunk).

Any thoughts/suggestions? Changing the core structure of the project is not an option. I have tried searching for previous discussions on this topic, but they all seem to cover only a part of the problem (like "how do I hide svn files/folders in eclipse?" or "Open Type does not find some classes") and none cover the entire span of eclipse + SVN + maven project with sub modules.

*The reason I still use this version is that there is no easy, out-of-the-box upgrade function for the Eclipse platform itself as far as I know (for version 3.4.x, that is), and I hate having to perform fresh install and then manually setting up everything the way I want and installing all plugins.

Comment: The update to Eclipse Indigo is simple, cause m2e can be installed via Marketplace from Eclipse and the SVN support as well...i would recommend to make a fresh download of Eclipse Indigo and configure is, cause it's much simpler than change the current installation, cause you are using old versions of plugins (of course based on your Eclipse version). Eclipse 3.4.2 is more than two years old..In particular the newest Maven Plugin for Eclipse is only available for Eclipse Indigo...Furthermore have you tried to update m2eclipse to 0.12 ?

Comment: I would suggest moving to Indigo only if the OP isn't using any non-standard Maven plugins, as starting from this version Maven plugins may require an Eclipse counterpart. On the other hand upgrading to Helios is definitely worth it, because lots of improvements were made both to m2eclipse and Subversive.

Comment: @Nicola. With m2e you can still run non-standard plugins.  Just change the `<action>` in the `lifecycle-mapping` pseudo-plugin to `<execute>`.  Read this document for better explanation -> http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered.  With execute on this is pretty much the behavior of m2eclipse.  Beware, though, that as with m2eclipse your mileage may wary depending on the actual plugin.  I believe this was exactly the reason why they redid plugin support in m2e.

Comment: @khmarbaise. Beware that your old `.project` and `.classpath` files for m2eclipse projects are not compatible with m2e. nature and build command in `.project` file has changed from m2eclipse to m2e, as well as full name for MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER in `.classpath`.  Nothing that find and replace cannot handle, but not as straight upgrade as it could have been.  If you don't have extensive eclipse customizations it may be better to reimport maven project with m2e into Indigo.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak: The real problem is I'm not likely to have the time to experiment with Indigo for the next few months, and as Helios works for us, we'll stick to that for the moment

Comment: @khmarbaise. So what you are saying is that the problem will likely get solved if I update to the latest Eclipse and plugins?

Answer (score 4):

I think if you do the following you will get everything you want.

1. From the repository explore checkout the parent project. IE the one containing the modules.
2. After checking out the project won't look right so delete it. DO NOT delete the sources.
3. Then do a file > import and import the parent project folder.

You should then see the parent and modules as separate projects and most (if not all) the requirements you listed should be fulfilled.

Comment: This is pretty much how I do it, too. Importing from SVN as a Maven project in one go doesn't always work properly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this would help. I just tried it, and requirement number still 5 fails...

Comment: @Jimi Where are you expecting to see the svn history? It should be visible in the package explorer.